# What is the correct way to assign a type to typescript members of a class

Tags: typescript

This is my code

```js
interface IClassMasks {
  arrMasksMultiple: string[];
  arrMasksSingle: string[];
  strMarker: string;
  strMarkerMaskName: string;
}

class ClassMasks implements IClassMasks {
  public arrMasksMultiple;
  public arrMasksSingle;
  public strMarker;
  public strMarkerMaskName;
  constructor() {
    this.arrMasksMultiple = [];
    this.arrMasksSingle = [];
    this.strMarker = null;
    this.strMarkerMaskName = 'strMarkerMask';
  }
}
```

When I hover over arrMasksMultiple inside my editor it says -

> Member 'arrMasksMultiple' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage

So if the member says - 'any' type then it can't be utilising the interface above.

Comment: `public arrMasksMultiple: string[];` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to declare the types of the fields inside your class; these types must also be compatible with the interface you are implementing. By default, the types are assumed implicitly as `any`, which is not compatible with the types defined in `IClassMasks`.

Furthermore, you cannot assign `null` to `IClassMasks.strMarker` because you did not specify that the type could also be `null`.

Here is what the amended typings would look like:

```
interface IClassMasks {
    arrMasksMultiple: string[];
    arrMasksSingle: string[];
    strMarker: string | null;  // indicate that this can also be a null value
    strMarkerMaskName: string;
}

class ClassMasks implements IClassMasks {
    // explicitly declare the types of these fields that are compatible with the IClassMasks interface
    public arrMasksMultiple: string[];
    public arrMasksSingle: string[];
    public strMarker: string | null; // indicate that this can also be a null value
    public strMarkerMaskName: string;
    constructor() {
        this.arrMasksMultiple = [];
        this.arrMasksSingle = [];
        this.strMarker = null;
        this.strMarkerMaskName = 'strMarkerMask';
    }
}
```

---

For brevity, you can also assign default values instead of assigning them in the constructor. Here's an example where the first 3 fields have default values.

```
class ClassMasks implements IClassMasks {
    public arrMasksMultiple: string[] = [];
    public arrMasksSingle: string[] = [];
    public strMarker: string | null = null;
    public strMarkerMaskName: string;
    constructor() {
        this.strMarkerMaskName = 'strMarkerMask';
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. This explains it. Though I wonder if its just easier declaring an object with the interface on the class rather than single variables for this very reason.